# Remix: Test Failed and the Message is " Transaction is reverted"

Tags: address.transfer, remix-tests

I am sending ETher from the test contract and then checking the balance but I am getting the message, Test Failed and Transaction is reverted.
My contracts are:

```
//pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

    pragma solidity ^0.5.3;
    import "remix_tests.sol"; 
    import "remix_accounts.sol";
    import "./STFB5.sol";
    import "./F5.sol";
    // File name has to end with '_test.sol', this file can contain more than one testSuite contracts
    contract testSuite {
        /// 'beforeAll' runs before all other tests
        /// More special functions are: 'beforeEach', 'beforeAll', 'afterEach' & 'afterAll'
        F5 obj1 = F5(0xd8b934580fcE35a11B58C6D73aDeE468a2833fa8);
        STFB5 obj2 = STFB5(0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138);
        address payable F5addr = 0xd8b934580fcE35a11B58C6D73aDeE468a2833fa8;
        address payable STFB5addr = 0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138;
       
        function beforeAll() public payable {
           uint a = 10;
           uint b = 20;
           F5addr.transfer(a);
           STFB5addr.transfer(b);
          
        }
         function initialValueofObj1ShouldBe100() public returns (bool) {
           return Assert.equal(obj1.getBalance(), 0, "initial value is not correct");
        }
        function initialValueofObj2ShouldBe100() public returns (bool) {
           return Assert.equal(obj2.getBalance(), 0, "initial value is not correct");
        }
     }

//STFB5.sol

    pragma solidity ^0.5.3;
    contract STFB5 {
        function transferToFallback(address payable _to) public payable {
            _to.transfer(msg.value);
        }
    
        
        function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
            return address(this).balance;
        }
        function () external payable {
    
        }
    }

//F5.sol

    pragma solidity ^0.5.3;
    
    contract F5 {
        
        function () external payable  {}
        // Helper function to check the balance of this contract
        function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
            return address(this).balance;
        }
       
    }
```

The output of running the test contract: STFB5_test.sol is:

```
FAIL testSuite (tests/Copy_STFB5_test.sol)
✘ Before all
Error Message:
"Transaction has been reverted by the EVM: { "transactionHash": "0x64ecdb166bcfa8c401735cad166f4aad4dc85ba8695a972557f2e94d2d1bb888", "transactionIndex": 0, "blockHash": "0xd41280b6b4bb1d8d132ecf2bc941c1d2ca47c07e59a1133bb214f44ee82909b9", "blockNumber": 15, "gasUsed": 32750, "cumulativeGasUsed": 32750, "status": false, "to": "0x9d83e140330758a8fFD07F8Bd73e86ebcA8a5692", "events": {} }"
✘ Initial valueof obj1 should be100
Error Message:
"Transaction has been reverted by the EVM: { "transactionHash": "0xf107ba86241746b12a9635e1eaef1e6b761356f7202d38594be34d6bf63d0e71", "transactionIndex": 0, "blockHash": "0x95b858e886318f16ebfa336536fe2d8610336a2e5f35343abe2563e0a9d2a0b8", "blockNumber": 16, "gasUsed": 26387, "cumulativeGasUsed": 26387, "status": false, "to": "0x9d83e140330758a8fFD07F8Bd73e86ebcA8a5692", "events": {} }"
✘ Initial valueof obj2 should be100
Error Message:
"Transaction has been reverted by the EVM: { "transactionHash": "0x5982b16ffdaa0e8fef25b5880abb4b5fa619a9566e0e9ab8b27f80bce4856138", "transactionIndex": 0, "blockHash": "0x253a34e3eb4cbb3eb50bab6119ca74ca9dc9c3aec3ce4a1c05ca8c70de085a9a", "blockNumber": 17, "gasUsed": 26431, "cumulativeGasUsed": 26431, "status": false, "to": "0x9d83e140330758a8fFD07F8Bd73e86ebcA8a5692", "events": {} }"
Result for tests/Copy_STFB5_test.sol
Failing: 3
Total time: 0.15s
```

Somebody please guide me. I stored all files in the test folder, otherwise it gives error.
Zulfi.